# Exclude specific Enum values from Swagger

Tags: c#, .net, enums, swagger, swashbuckle

I always add an `Uninitialized` value to all my enums and set it to `0` to handle cases where I deserialize an object that has an enum property value that was never set.

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Uninitialized = 0,
    MyEnumValue1 = 1,
    MyEnumValue2 = 2,
    MyEnumValue3 = 3,
}
```

However, I don't want the `Uninitialized` value to show up in my Swagger documentation.

I've tried adding the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute to that value, but that didn't work.

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using Swachbuckle to generate Swagger page ?

Comment: @ysabih Yes. I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore v4.0.2

Comment: Swashbuckle does not support hiding enum members, you'll have to wrap the enum in a class and then use [JsonIngore], here is a detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52310219/7248501

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just in case anyone else struggles with this. You can create a custom SchemaFilter and populate the `Enum` property filtering on those enum values with a custom attribute (in this example: `OpenApiIgnoreEnumAttribute`).

```
    public class OpenApiIgnoreEnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
    {
        public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context.Type.IsEnum)
            {
                var enumOpenApiStrings = new List<IOpenApiAny>();

                foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(context.Type))
                {
                    var member = context.Type.GetMember(enumValue.ToString())[0];
                    if (!member.GetCustomAttributes<OpenApiIgnoreEnumAttribute>().Any())
                    {
                        enumOpenApiStrings.Add(new OpenApiString(enumValue.ToString()));
                    }
                }

                schema.Enum = enumOpenApiStrings;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public class OpenApiIgnoreEnumAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
```

```
    public enum ApplicationRole
    {
        [OpenApiIgnoreEnum]        
        DoNotExpose = 1,        
        ValueA = 2,        
        ValueB = 3,
    }
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution, thank you! One improvement that I had to make, however, was handling nullable types:

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IDocumentFilter` to remove anything you want from the specs.

It might not be intuitive at first, look at some of the examples they have:
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/search?q=IDocumentFilter

With that you are able to change the swagger json spec to remove or inject anything you want.
Now be careful you could end up with a non-compliant spec, always check it against the validator: https://validator.swagger.io/validator/debug?url=http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1

Answer (score 1):

You can simply omit your `Uninitialized` enum value to solve this.

Enums can actually contain values other than the ones you explicitly define. I can do `var myEnumValue = (MyEnum)12345;` and it won't break or throw an exception, but it won't match any of the explicitly defined enum values either.

As long as the defined values do not equal `default(int)`, or the default of whatever you chose your enum type to be, you can still work with the enum as expected, and catch unitialized values with a `switch default` case.

This has the added benefit of catching *all* unlisted enum values, not just the one you explicitly declared.

Comment: Although this doesn't directly answer my question, it actually goes further in that it explains the flaw in my thinking which led to the question being asked in the first place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Royston46's answer was excellent and helped build a foundation, but I had to make a couple of modifications to get it to fully work for my scenario.

The first issue was handling nullable types. If the underlying property associated with the enum is nullable, context.Type.IsEnum will return false.

The second issue is that finding the member by value to examine the custom attributes won't work correctly when you have multiple enums with the same value. In our case, we deprecated some old enum names, but left them in the enum for compatibility with existing API consumers. However, we needed the documentation to only show the new names.

Here is the revised implementation that we built from Royston46's excellent answer:

```
public class OpenApiIgnoreEnumSchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiSchema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.Type.IsEnum || (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(context.Type)?.IsEnum ?? false))
        {
            var type = context.Type.IsEnum ? context.Type : Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(context.Type);

            var enumOpenApiStrings = new List<IOpenApiAny>();

            foreach (var enumName in Enum.GetNames(type))
            {
                var member = type.GetMember(enumName)[0];
                if (!member.GetCustomAttributes<OpenApiIgnoreEnumAttribute>().Any())
                {
                    enumOpenApiStrings.Add(new OpenApiString(enumName));
                }
            }

            schema.Enum = enumOpenApiStrings;
        }
    }
}
```