# Exclude specific Enum values from JSON Schema/Swagger

Tags: javascript, swagger, jsonschema

I'm working with a JavaScript API defined using JSON Schema. The API has an enum field with the following values.

`enum: ['apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'tester'].`

The schema also describes the swagger. I want to hide the value `tester` from Swagger but display the other values.
Similar to this question in C# [Exclude specific Enum values from Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54933188/exclude-specific-enum-values-from-swagger?rq=3)

Is there a way to achieve this in JavaScript?